# How to perform a specific calculation like 1500*20/100 using PDO or MYSQLI?

Tags: php, sql

I am not sure how to perform good calculations.  Example, you have inserted a value into the pay Column, lets say there is an input of $1500 and you have a Pay2 column that is blank.     I want to take the 1500 and take 20% off, so I was thinking Pay*20/100 and then it would input 1200 into the Pay2 column. So in the same row, I would have 1500 and 1200.  Any help would be great.

Select Pay Column in a database, do the calculation and insert it into the Pay2 column in the same row.

This could be any value, it does not have to be 1500, it could be 900 or 90.

SELECT Pay FROM database 
MPay = Pay*20/100

UPDATE Pay2 Set MPay = Pay2

Comment: So have you tried this formula?  What doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: that's the way you can offer a 20% discount. did you tried it ?

Comment: I have not tried the formula.  I am stuck on how I should use select or insert and don't know how to get started.  I am trying to find a good example.

Comment: You're describing a derived value which is the result of a simple calculation. Unless this value is only valid at the point you insert it then you should not store it in the database but rather calculate it when you need it.

Comment: Google is pretty effective for finding tutorials and examples.  I suggest you start there and then come back here when you get stuck

Comment: Well, I have search google but maybe I am not using the correct words in the search to find the correct examples.  I have found sum examples.

Comment: Yes this is a simple calculation but I am trying to find a good example using Select Pay Column, do a calculation and insert it into the Pay2 column in the same row.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to take a percentage off of a value you can use this function

```
    // this function returns amount after discount

    function calcDiscount($percentage, $pay){   
       return $pay - (($percentage/100) * $pay);
    }

   // call the function

   $pay = 1500;
   $discount = 20;
   $pay2 = calcDiscount($discount, $pay);
```

So in your pdo and sql coding you can call the function:

```
//this code works for this $id. For multiple id's you will need a loop    
$id = 1;
$discount = 20;

$conn = pdo_connect();

$sql = 'SELECT      Pay1
        FROM        Your_Table
        WHERE       ID = :ID';

$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(":ID", $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$statement->execute();

// 1. get the pay1 from the row
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// store the value in a variable
$pay = $result[0]['Pay1'];

// 2. calculate the discount for Pay1
$pay2 = calcDiscount($discount, $pay);

// 3. update the column for pay2
$sql = 'UPDATE Your_Table
        SET Pay2 = :pay2
        WHERE ID = :ID';

$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(":pay2", $pay2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->bindValue(":ID", $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);


$statement->execute();

$conn = null;
```

For your MySQL statements, you actually want to use SELECT to grab the pay from a table and UPDATE to change the value in a column

Comment: How is this an answer to OP's question?

Comment: Well, I don't want to update the Pay column, I just want to insert it into a Pay2 column so I can see the original pay and the discounted pay.  I don't want to change any numbers in the pay column. I try this out and see.  It might work.

Comment: Yup, this should only update a second column. In the example its called 'Name_of_Pay2_Column'.

Comment: What if the number isn't 1500, it could be a value of 900 or some other numbers and I don't want to change it all the time.  I want it to change all the numbers no matter what the values.

Comment: Yes, in last block of code, $pay will take any value that is given from the query.  

Check it out, the code actually does 3 things:
1. query the row and get the original value in the pay column
2. calculate the discount
3. update the row with discount value, not changing the original value

Comment: You could start with an array of row id's. Then loop through the array calling the code above for each id.